# PHP5/MYSQL - IF value1 = value2 then die else do code

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple `IF`:

```
IF $un = mysql_result
  die
else
  do some code.
```

This is for the process form to prevent multiple users with the same name.

`$UN` is a variable declared at the beginning of the PHP from a registration form.

Problem is, it hits everything as taken, even though it isn't:

```
if ($result = '$UN') {
  $errorMessage = "Name has been Taken";
  echo "User name is allready being Used, ";
  $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errormessage;
  echo " Please Go Back and Try Again";
  //header("Location: register.php");
  exit();
}
else {
  echo "not taken -- ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` condition, replace the single equals `=` with double equals `==` to do a comparison. Better still, use the triple equals operator `===`, which compares the types too.

Also, remove the quotes from the `$UN` variable you are using so that its actual value is used in the comparison.

Comment: i tried if ($result === $UN){  and the other solution "if ($result == '$UN") { both bring back incorrect values

Comment: Did you also try `if ($result == $UN)`?

Answer (score 0):

It hits everything as taken because that's an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.'

```
if($result == '$UN') {
// your code
}
```

Are you sure you want to compare the $result to a string '$UN'? That's a weird character to match. Might want to check on that.

Comment: The code you've pasted shows '$UN', not $UN. The enclosing quotes make that a string, not a variable. Remove the quotes from $UN to compare the two variables.

Comment: Try var_dump($UN) and var_dump($result) to see what they contain. If they do not contain the correct values, double check how you assigned them.

Comment: -- THIS FIXED MY PROBLEM --> 
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $errorMessage21 = "Name has been Taken";
    echo "User name is allready being Used, ";
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errormessage21;
    echo " Please Go Back and Try Again";
    //header("Location: register.php");
    exit();
 } else {
    echo "not taken -- ";
 } // <-- end there